# Trying to create custom MonthCalendar - Can't get inheritance to work

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I'm attempting to customise the MonthCalendar control but I've failed at the first hurdle. If I add the following line to my control class:

```
Inherits MonthCalendar
```

I get an error saying Base class 'System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar' specified for class 'ScheduleCalendar' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' or one of its other partial types.

The IDE then gives me the option to change MonthCalendar to UserControl or change UserControl in ScheduleCalendar.Designer.vb to MonthCalendar. When I change both to MonthCalendar (which is what seems to be suggested on MSDN) I then get this error: 'AutoScaleMode' is not a member of 'ScheduleCalendar.SheduleCalendar' for the code in the designer.vb file:

```
'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'ScheduleCalendar
    '
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Inherit
    Me.Name = "ScheduleCalendar"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
```

If I comment out the AutoScaleMode then I get an error in design view and the control can't be displayed.

Comment: You have to get started correctly, and that's *not* by picking the "User Control" project item template.  Use Project + Add Class instead.  Then it is simply Public Class MyCalendar / Inherits MonthCalender / End Class.

Comment: Thank you. My intention is to make a calendar which will allow multiple individual dates to be selected independently instead of a range. Would it be easier to attempt to customise the existing calendar, or create my own from scratch?